# ImportError: cannot import name '_assert_shallow_structure' from 'tree'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I am getting that error while importing tensorflow_probability in IDLE(Default python editor). I don't get that error if use same code in VS code. Works perfectly fine in VS code.
Here are my imports

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Here is complete error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python Scripts\pos_tagging.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tensorflow_probability as tfp
  File "C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python import bijectors
  File "C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.bijectors.absolute_value import AbsoluteValue
  File "C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\absolute_value.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.bijectors import bijector
  File "C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\bijector.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal import distribution_util
  File "C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\distribution_util.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal import prefer_static
  File "C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\prefer_static.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal.backend import numpy as nptf
  File "C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\backend\numpy\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal.backend.numpy import bitwise
  File "C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\backend\numpy\bitwise.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal.backend.numpy import _utils as utils
  File "C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\backend\numpy\_utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal.backend.numpy import nest
  File "C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\backend\numpy\nest.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tree import _assert_shallow_structure
ImportError: cannot import name '_assert_shallow_structure' from 'tree' (C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\idlelib\tree.py)
```

Python Version:3.8.5 64 bit
Windows machine

Comment: Is this the correct file `"C:\Python Scripts\pos_tagging.py"`, the reason why I am asking this is, as per your post you haven't imported this `from tree import _assert_shallow_structure`

Comment: C:\Python Scripts\pos_tagging.py is what I am trying to run. And I haven't imported 'from tree import _assert_shallow_structure '  and I have no idea why it is showing up .

Answer (score 0):

Look at where it's importing from (C:\Users\aaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\idlelib\tree.py) I think you meant to import from dm-tree.

Here's my solution:
if you don't have dm-tree installed

```
pip install dm-tree
```

if you do, install PyCharm and use that to run the code. It wont have the conflict that IDLE would on the tree.py